# Ruby/SQLite3 results as hash returns duplicate data

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, sqlite3-ruby

I have the following code in my app.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'sqlite3'

get '/api/clients' do
  db = SQLite3::Database.new "db/db"
  db.results_as_hash = true
  {clients: db.execute('SELECT * FROM clients')}.to_json
end
```

Inspecting the results in the browser, we see this:

[image]

Why is the hash as well as the array being returned when I've set `db.results_as_hash = true`?

Comment: looks like it's intentionally developed like this, to support referencing values by both name and index: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/177763

Comment: @w0lf, I'm not sure why this is the case. It really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Line 584](https://github.com/audibleblink/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L584) of the source shows that the records come back as key-value pairs, where the column names are keys and the values are the record's data. It also inserts index values for the headers. Presumably, this is to preserve order dependance in the results hash for older versions of Ruby. Ruby > 1.9 preserves insertion order.

The gem [returns a ResultSet as an array](https://github.com/audibleblink/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L137) of results. If a user sets `results_as_hash` to `true`, the inner arrays are turned into the hashes you're seeing.